# run Windows 8.1 app inside Windows 10 preview

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, windows-10

When I run my Windows 8.1 app inside Windows 10 preview (build 10240 and also all prior versions) all controls are quite tiny.

Normally the screen has 1366x768 physical pixels (and a scaling factor of 1.0 was reported).

When running the Windows 8.1 app inside Windows 10, a logical resolution of 1645.783... x 925.301... is reported (and still a scaling factor of 1.0 is reported).

Windows 10 then seems to downscale the 1645.783... x 925.301 "pixels" to the 1366x768 physical pixels which leads in notably smaller controls (while more content is shown)

The "magic factor" is 1.2048... which is exactly 1.0 / 0.83.

I know that Windows 10 has new scaling plateus. But this all does not make sense at all. The artificial scaling has an akward factor. Actually, leaving 1366x768 (@1.0) would be perfect. I consider this as a serious bug.

What is Windows 10 doing?

(I could port my Win 8.1 app to Win 10 so that the scaling would be OK again, but I would like to wait some months till the tools are really ready)

Comment: You shouldn't see 1.2048 as a scale factor - can you reproduce this in a simple app (File -> New Project)? What is the exact hardware you are running on?

Answer (score 0):

In Windows 10 display scaling affects both desktop apps and Windows apps. In Windows 8 however, display scaling only affected desktop apps. Your issue might be linked to this. Check your display scaling in Settings > System > Display > "Change the size of text, apps and other items".